# create pascol voc xml from csv

Tags: python, xml, csv

I am stuck here.
I am generating annotation `xml` from csv file which contains lots of images name, classes, and bounding box information.

I want to make xml files separately based on class.

eg: If I want `class == traffic_sign` , then each  xml (for each images) will be containing only `traffic_sign` and corresponding information.You can see example below:

and If I want to add one more class (let say class == cross_road)then xml will include traffic_sign and cross_road based on csv information.

I have given one example here:

I wanted only traffic_sign and corresponding information, then xml was created for image `1.jpg` as below:

```xml
<annotation>
    <folder>./5/xmls</folder>
    <filename>1.jpg</filename>
    <path>./1.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1920</width>
        <height>1080</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>traffic_sign</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>886.89</xmin>
            <ymin>517.56</ymin>
            <xmax>931.46</xmax>
            <ymax>562.51</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
    <object>
        <name>traffic_sign</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>783.00</xmin>
            <ymin>432.58</ymin>
            <xmax>835.14</xmax>
            <ymax>485.09</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

my csv format is like this:

```
filename           width    height  class            xmin     ymin   xmax   ymax
MP_KSC_021405.jpg   1920    1080    traffic_sign    1316.66 681.51  1358.14 717.92
MP_SEL_083698.jpg   1920    1080    traffic_sign    735.44  117.14  827.45  200.42
MP_SEL_083698.jpg   1920    1080    traffic_sign    733.06  201.22  825.07  289.26
MP_KSC_010168.jpg   1920    1080    traffic_sign    617.39  301.83  697.12  423.66
```

filename contains all the images, and class contains all the class.

I want separate xml for each images.
And each xml file will include all the classes and bounding boxes related to that image. This is so far I have done in Python:

```py
import pandas
import numpy
import os
# from tqdm import tqdm_notebook

from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse, Element, SubElement, ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


#save_root1 = "./traffic_light"
save_root2 = "./test/xmls"


#if not os.path.exists(save_root1):
#    os.mkdir(save_root1)

if not os.path.exists(save_root2):
    os.mkdir(save_root2)

def write_xml(folder, filename, width, height, bbox_list):
    root = Element('annotation')
    SubElement(root, 'folder').text = folder
    SubElement(root, 'filename').text = filename
    SubElement(root, 'path').text = './images' +  filename
    source = SubElement(root, 'source')
    SubElement(source, 'database').text = 'Unknown'

    size = SubElement(root, 'size')
    SubElement(size, 'width').text = str(width)
    SubElement(size, 'height').text = str(height)
    SubElement(size, 'depth').text = '3'

    SubElement(root, 'segmented').text = '0'

    for i in bbox_list:
        obj = SubElement(root, 'object')
        SubElement(obj, 'name').text = i[0]
        SubElement(obj, 'pose').text = 'Unspecified'
        SubElement(obj, 'truncated').text = '0'
        SubElement(obj, 'difficult').text = '0'

        bbox = SubElement(obj, 'bndbox')
        SubElement(bbox, 'xmin').text = str(i[1])
        SubElement(bbox, 'ymin').text = str(i[2])
        SubElement(bbox, 'xmax').text = str(i[3])
        SubElement(bbox, 'ymax').text = str(i[4])

    indent(root)
    tree = ElementTree(root)
    tree.write('./'+folder + '/' + filename.split('.')[0] +'.xml')
    

seed_arr = []

file = open('./test/labels.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
#read csv data
for index, line in enumerate(csv_reader):
    # pass csv header == index[0]
    if index == 0:
        continue
    seed_arr.append(line)
file.close()

sign = 0
print(seed_arr[3])
for index, line in enumerate(seed_arr):
    label = line[3]
    if label == "traffic_sign":
        sign += 1    
        filename = line[0]
        width = line[1]
        height = line[2]
        class_name = line[3]
        xmin = line[4]
        ymin = line[5]
        xmax = line[6]
        ymax = line[7]
        sign+= 1

    if sign > 0:
        write_xml(save_root2, file_nm, width, height, bbox_list)
```

I hope to get some help here.

Thank you so much guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you are trying to combine all the entries with the same filename, as such for your example CSV `MP_SEL_083698.jpg` needs two entries in the XML.

To achieve this, you could use a `defaultdict()` to build a dictionary containing a list of all entries with the keys being the filename.

Each list of rows can then be passed to your `write_xml()` function to save them:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import os
import csv

from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse, Element, SubElement, ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

save_root2 = "xmls"

if not os.path.exists(save_root2):
    os.mkdir(save_root2)


def write_xml(folder, filename, bbox_list):
    root = Element('annotation')
    SubElement(root, 'folder').text = folder
    SubElement(root, 'filename').text = filename
    SubElement(root, 'path').text = './images' +  filename
    source = SubElement(root, 'source')
    SubElement(source, 'database').text = 'Unknown'


    # Details from first entry
    e_filename, e_width, e_height, e_class_name, e_xmin, e_ymin, e_xmax, e_ymax = bbox_list[0]
    
    size = SubElement(root, 'size')
    SubElement(size, 'width').text = e_width
    SubElement(size, 'height').text = e_height
    SubElement(size, 'depth').text = '3'

    SubElement(root, 'segmented').text = '0'

    for entry in bbox_list:
        e_filename, e_width, e_height, e_class_name, e_xmin, e_ymin, e_xmax, e_ymax = entry
        
        obj = SubElement(root, 'object')
        SubElement(obj, 'name').text = e_class_name
        SubElement(obj, 'pose').text = 'Unspecified'
        SubElement(obj, 'truncated').text = '0'
        SubElement(obj, 'difficult').text = '0'

        bbox = SubElement(obj, 'bndbox')
        SubElement(bbox, 'xmin').text = e_xmin
        SubElement(bbox, 'ymin').text = e_ymin
        SubElement(bbox, 'xmax').text = e_xmax
        SubElement(bbox, 'ymax').text = e_ymax

    #indent(root)
    tree = ElementTree(root)
    
    xml_filename = os.path.join('.', folder, os.path.splitext(filename)[0] + '.xml')
    tree.write(xml_filename)
    

entries_by_filename = defaultdict(list)

with open('labels.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f_input_csv:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input_csv)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for row in csv_input:
        filename, width, height, class_name, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = row

        if class_name == "traffic_sign":
            entries_by_filename[filename].append(row)

for filename, entries in entries_by_filename.items():
    print(filename, len(entries))
    write_xml(save_root2, filename, entries)
```

You can also use `next()` to skip over the header row.

Comment: Hi @Martin , thanks for your effort.Really appreciate it. One more question, If I have more classes then I can just give elif or else conditions right?

Comment: Depends if you want to combine them into the same files or use different files, if the same files then you could just use `if class_name in ["traffic_sign", "car", "bike"]:`

Comment: I saw many people are asking help to convert csv to xml. I will share it in github.Thank Martin.